# Split image src attribute with plain vanilla JavaScript and no Regex

Tags: javascript, dom, split, attributes

### The Issue

I'm trying to figure out how to split a src element with plain vanilla JavaScript for an `<img>` tag. I think my code is pretty solid but Chrome developer console keeps giving me  "someFunction is not a function errors".

### My Code

Here is my current code:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i) {

   console.log(links[i].src);

   var partsArr = links[i].toString().split('/');
   console.log(partsArr);


}
```

It runs, but the output I get for partsArr is:

`["[object HTMLImageElement]"]`

I was expecting something more like:

`["file:","pathpart1", "pathpart2", ... "filename.ext"]`

**NOTE:** I have to do this with plain JavaScript because jQuery isn't available. Also, it's a page on localhost, and I'm coding in Chrome developer tools console, if that makes a difference.

### What I've Tried Already

I have already searched for a duplicate and have not found one that exactly answers what I am asking. Here are the posts I referenced before submitting this question:

[Javascript: Split and variable issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612568/javascript-split-and-variable-issues)
[Split a image tag on html string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978381/split-a-image-tag-on-html-string)
[Getting image src name javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522441/getting-image-src-name-javascript)
[How to split and assign 2 words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489928/how-to-split-and-assign-2-words)
[What is causing the error `string.split is not a function`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145946/what-is-causing-the-following-error-string-split-is-not-a-function-in-javascr)

### My Questions

1. How do I parse the image file name from an `<img>` tag src attribute, using just plain vanilla JavaScript, and no regexes?
2. What am I doing wrong in my current code?

Comment: It looks like this part is wrong, 'var partsArr = links[i].toString().split('/');' Instead of executing 'toString' on the element object, you should just access the .src property from the element.

So, var partsArr = links[i].src.split('/');

Comment: @MichaelCamden You are a lifesaver! I figured I was off by one or two characters somewhere. Such a simple solution. If you post this as an answer, instead of a comment, I will mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this part is wrong,

```
var partsArr = links[i].toString().split('/');
```

Instead of executing 'toString' on the element object, you should just access the .src property from the element. So,

```
var partsArr = links[i].src.split('/');
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author)*.

Many thanks to Michael Camden for providing me another set of eyes and finding my mistake. After making the correction he suggested, the code works perfectly.

For anyone else looking for a plain JavaScript way to get all the image names from a webpage without all the file path location info, here is the script I wrote that works like a charm:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

for (var i=0; i<links.length; ++i) {

   console.log(links[i].src);

   var partsArr = links[i].src.split('/');
   console.log(partsArr);

   var imageName = partsArr[partsArr.length -1];
   console.log(imageName);


}
```